# Testing for a column, losing my mind

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF ((SELECT count(name) FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'foobar') > 0)
BEGIN 
        SELECT 'exists' 
    --, foobar FROM baz -- <--rename this to a table that exists
END
ELSE
SELECT 'boo'

IF (exists(SELECT name FROM syscolumns WHERE name = 'foobar'))
BEGIN
    SELECT 'exists' 
    --, foobar FROM baz -- <--rename this to a table that exists
END
ELSE
    SELECT 'boo'
```

Both of these statements should produce 'boo' for you (run 'em against any db).

UNCOMMENT the second SELECT value in each query (the foobar)...

As far as I can tell, the @!%$ing engine EVALUATES ALL EXPRESSIONS WHETHER THEY ARE HIT OR NOT!!!  NEVER MIND THE LOGIC!

Am I high?  Confused?  Stupid?

Sorry for the all caps, just really frustrated over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to understand what the problem is. If the DB Engine is telling you:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'foobar'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'foobar'.
```

then that is the expected behaviour. Heard of runtime / compile time errors?

Try changing the column to something that exists and it will work fine. The problem is, even though the logic is that this code block will never execute, still when the SQL is compiled, the DB engine evaluates and determines that the column does not exist. Hence the error.

Comment: I'm befuddled, though -- the logic works as expected, until I include the tested field in the BEGIN/END block of the path of True... and then it barfs telling me the column doesn't exist.  I would expect that if the column doesn't exist, it wouldn't evaluate that portion in the first place.

Comment: Try changing the column to something that exists and it will work fine. The problem is, even though the logic is that this code block will never execute, still when the SQL is compiled, the DB engine evaluates and determines that the column does not exist. Hence the error.

Comment: Ahhh - That explains it.... Looks like I need to pull the logic out of my dynamic SQL and into another chunk of execution.  Thanks!

Comment: can you replace your answer with your comment?  I will happily accept it then.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `EXEC`?

And `COL_LENGTH` to find existance of the column, as it's a much better way than checking syscolumns IMO.

```
IF COL_LENGTH('foobar','foo') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 


        EXEC ('SELECT ''exists'' 
    , foo FROM foobar') -- <--rename this to a table that exists
END
ELSE
SELECT 'boo'
```

Comment: I will explore this -- thanks!  The above example is just the bare bones of a problem with some dynamic SQL I've been beating my skull against.

Answer (score 0):

After 10 mins of frustration, I finally got it. Although I am not 100% sure whether you are allowed to specify un existing columns, there is possible workarounds such as:

```
    IF ((SELECT count(name) FROM syscolumns WHERE name= 'foobar') > 0)
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'  SELECT foobar FROM #temp1 -- <--rename this to a table that    exists;';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
    ELSE
    SELECT 'boo'
```

Comment: Uhhh... That's kind of the point.  It seems to evaluate the select statement and barf, even if the logic dictates that that section will not be executed.